# PowerShell -replace old,new -- multiple replacements possible?

Tags: powershell

I need to use PowerShell 5.1 to read a file, make edits to it, and write the results to another file.  I've been studying https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540444/grep-and-sed-not-working-in-powershell and have been able to adapt the information there to something close to what I want, which is currently the following:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-Content $$source_file -Raw) -replace 'AAA','BBB' | Out-File -filepath output_file"
```

That works, but I have two issues for which I haven't yet found an answer:

1. Because the instruction above is part of a recipe in a Makefile which must use cmd.exe as its shell (otherwise I'd just use sed), I need to phrase the instruction as-is, i.e. with the actual PowerShell command being passed as a character string between two double quotes.  Using single quotes around the values of the -replace arguments works, but in the real life problem I need to pass variables, so I have to use double quotes so that the variable references can be expanded.  I read elsewhere that to include a double quote in a powershell instruction just to use two double quotes in a row, but when I do so I get an error message that I must use a value expression after the `-replace` operator.

Here is the version that doesn't work:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-Content $$source_file -Raw) -replace ""AAA"",""BBB"" | Out-File -filepath output_file"
```

So my first question is, how can I include a variable name in the value expression in a way that will allow it to be expanded to its real value?

My second question is, I need to make more than one edit to the file.  Since the `-replace` operator seems to be tied to the Get-Content commandlet, I tried the following:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-Content $$source_file -Raw) -replace 'AAA','BBB' -replace 'CCC','DDD' | Out-File -filepath output_file"
```

The presence of the second `-replace` expression raised an error exception.  So if I need to make several edits to the source file on the fly before the final version is written back to the file system, is there a simple way to do it other than sending the entire file through a new Get-Content pipe again for every edit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would help to see the error you get.

Here it works with two replace in a cmd window.

Alternatively you can try the `.replace('AAA','BBB')` method.

```
> type test.txt
blah AAA
Blubb CCC

> PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -C "(Get-Content .\test.txt -Raw) -replace 'AAA','BBB' -replace 'CCC','DDD' "

blah BBB
Blubb DDD

> PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -C "(Get-Content .\test.txt -Raw).replace('AAA','BBB').replace('CCC','DDD')"
blah BBB
Blubb DDD
```

Comment: Hi LotPings, I was not aware of the second way of doing it (using .replace instead of -replace).  I tried it, with two in a row, and it worked!  That solves my problem.  Thank you much!

Comment: Be aware that the `-replace` operator uses RegEx while the `.replace()` method does not. Both can come in handy.